# abort ajax and timer completely

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

I'm looking to abort an ajax request and its timer thats inside a function:

```
var run_timer;
var run;
function myrequest() {

    if(run && run.readystate != 4){ run.abort(); }

    run = $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"https://www.URL.com",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: "string=1",
        timeout: 10000,
        error: function(data) {
            run.abort();
            run_timer = setTimeout(function(){
                myrequest()
            }, 2000);
        },
        success: function(data){
             alert('success')
        }
    });
}

function stop_request() {
    clearTimeout(run_timer);
    run.abort();
}
```

if I call stop_request() it aborts the current ajax request but it looks as though the timer is still going which then causes another request made. How do I stop it altogether?

Comment: Does error event trigger maybe?

Comment: its doesn't or shouldn't...it will only trigger if the target file has an error (which it doesn't)  or the timeout exceeds 10 seconds. but If i make the request and abort it after 2 seconds it still does another request

Comment: Simple enough to check if `error:` is triggering on abort - it is for my test.  http://jsfiddle.net/ndkse9yq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `ajax.abort()` (in your case `run.abort()`) you also get the `error:` and `.fail()` callbacks - at which point you **start a new request**.

A simple `console.log` or debugging in `error:` would confirm this.

Because `run.abort()` runs immediately (not asynchronously) you can cancel the new timer after it is created:

```
function stop_request() {
  clearTimeout(run_timer);
  run.abort();  // creates a new run_timer
  clearTimeout(run_timer);
}
```

Comment: Also, something to keep in mind: You can abort a request, but that's only the client side. The server side could still be processing the request...

Comment: That did the trick!...completely forgot to check the console! massive reminder in doing so in the future...Many thanks for taking the time to explain the problem and resolution!